# Increasing size of XFS partition

Tags: linux, partitioning, xfs

I've installed Fedora Server ARM on the sdcard of my cubietruck, and now the system partition is full, and I want to expand it.
The sdcard have a size of 7.5GiB.

```
Gerät          Boot  Anfang     Ende Sektoren Größe Kn Typ
/dev/mmcblk0p1         2048  1001471   999424   488M 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p2      1001472  2001953  1000482 488,5M 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p3      2001954  7861328  5859375   2,8G 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p4      7862272 15710207  7847936   3,8G 83 Linux
```

I want to make `/dev/mmcblk0p3` and `/dev/mmcblk0p4` to one large partition, `/dev/mmcblk0p4` is completely empty.

I tryed already `sudo xfs_growfs /dev/mmcblk0p3 -D 732421` and other higher blocksizes, but the system always says that the maximum size is 732421.

Can someone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First things first back up your data prior to making any of the suggested changes.

You can remove the partition /dev/mmcblk0p4 then using fdisk add that space to the /dev/mmcblk0p3 location. Once you do that you should be able to expand the xfs file system to a larger size. I have had to do this a few times with VMs that were not build with LVM.

Comment: How to do this in fdisk? I only found some solutions were I must create the partitions new and copy the files over to the new one.

Comment: You first have to delete the partion that you are not using. Then commit that. Then after you commit that and restart fdisk it should see the free space that can be added to your existing partition.